# how to put variable in python defaultdict call

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict

In a python defaultdict object (like obj1), I can call `obj1['hello','there']` and get item. but when the input list is variable (for example: `input_list`), how I can call `obj1[input_list]`?
when I call `obj1[input_list]`, python raise this error:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

when use `obj1[*input_list]`, python returns:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

So what is the correct way to put list as variable in defaultdict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` states that list is not hashable, but a dict always needs a hashable key!
If you test `my_normal_dict[2,3]` you can see that it actually treats these two numbers as the tuple `(2,3)` because the error is `KeyError: (2, 3)`, so you need to input a hashable iterable like a tuple.

For example, `my_dict[tuple(my_list)]` should work, as long as all the elements of the tuple itself are hashable!
Note though: If your list is large, it may be relevant that this needs to copy all elements into a tuple.